# Depth-first/breadth-first algorithm printing all nodes; how do I get it to only print nodes in the path?

Tags: java, algorithm, nodes, depth-first-search, adjacency-matrix

I have an adjacency matrix `adj` of the form below:

```
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

This is the adjacency matrix for a maze with rules `adj(x,y) = 1` if:

1. x != y
2. x is adjacent to y
3. neither x or y is a wall in the maze

The maze is as below (beside it are the element numbers):

```
S X E | 1 2 3
O O O | 4 5 6
O X O | 7 8 9
//S = starting position
//E = ending position
//X = wall
```

I have a DFS algorithm that will display the nodes to traverse from `S` to `E`, but it displays unnecessary nodes.

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    int[][] adj = //the adjacency matrix
    boolean[] visited = new boolean[adj.length];
    int n = adj.length;    
    int m = 1; //starting position
    int o = 3; //ending position
    DFS(adjMatrix, visited, n, m, o);
}

public static void DFS(int[][] adj, boolean[] visited, int n, int i, int o){
    System.out.print(" " + (i+1));
    visited[i]= true;
    if (i+1 != o) {
        for (int j = 0; j<n;j++){
            if(!(visited[j]) && adj[i][j]==1){
               DFS(adj, visited, n, j, o);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void BFS(int[][] adj, boolean[] visited, int n, int i, int o){
    queue Q = new queue;
    visited[i]= true;
    Q.enqueue(i);
    while (!Q.isEmpty()) {
        //...
    }
}
```

This prints `1 4 5 6 3 9 7`. I'm wracking my head around modifying it so that it will only print `1 4 5 6 3`.

What have I done wrong here?

Comment: add a check in DFS function, when you reach your desire location. (i.e. o) return from DFS.

Comment: note that, if you want to find the shortest path, a BFS would be even better.

Comment: @riista imagine a 100x100, fully-empty map, with start at top-left corner and end at center. BFS can decide to "spiral in", painting everything; or in the best case paint half the map; in either case, the returned paths would be long and windy. Breadth-first would only paint half the map, and return the optimum path.

Comment: @riista DPS go as deep as possible right away, so most likely (more obviously in larger graphs) if it finds a path, it won't be the shortest. BFS expand out layer by layer from the "root", so if it finds a path, it's probably the shortest.

Comment: @Carcigenicate probably -> provably. One way of looking at it is that Dijkstra is optimal, and if all edges have the same costs, BFS is Dijkstra.

Comment: @tucuxi, I've put in an attempt at BFS by editing OP.

Comment: @riista - you are not supposed to change questions on the fly (except to clarify). The right thing is to ask a new question

Comment: @tucuxi, my mistake. I've posted a new question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some major issues with the code, in addition to fixes needed for the DFS algorithm:

- You Start and end are wrong: it should be decreased by 1 (because the
  indices are 0 based)
- <strike>Your adjanecy matrix is wrong (it is of size `10X9` - it should be a squared matrix)</strike>(edit fixed it)
- Your solution should only print elements that are in the path. One way to do it would be to return a `List<>` (rather than `void` - that populates all the nodes in the current path. If you reached the destination, create the list, otherwise - return `null`. Attach elements only when the recursive call returns something that is not `null`. Code attached

Also note, it prints the nodes in the correct order (and not reversed order)

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    int[][] adj = {
            {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, 
            {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, 
            {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, 
            {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, 
            {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0} 
    };
    boolean[] visited = new boolean[adj.length];
    int n = adj.length;    
    int m = 1-1; //starting position
    int o = 3-1; //ending position
    System.out.println(DFS(adj, visited, n, m, o));
}

public static List<Integer> DFS(int[][] adj, boolean[] visited, int n, int i, int o){
    visited[i]= true;
    if (i == o) return new LinkedList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(i+1));
    for (int j = 0; j<n;j++){
        if(!(visited[j]) && adj[i][j]==1){
            List<Integer> res = DFS(adj, visited, n, j, o);
            if (res != null) { 
                res.add(0, i+1);
                return res;
            }
        }
    }
    return null; //no path
}
```

Will result (as expected) with:

```
[1, 4, 5, 6, 3]
```

---

As a side note, though this solution is *complete* (will always find a solution if such exists), it is not *optimal* - it might return a longer solution than the shortest one.

If you want to find the shortest path from source to target, consider switching to a [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)

Comment: Nice full program. Also, I had never seen `Arrays.asList` used for single elements

Comment: @tucuxi The signature is `Arrays.asList(T...)`, it could be used with zero elements as well.

Comment: A BFS implementation would instead use a queue in place of a List, correct?

Comment: @riista No. BFS will be an iterative solution, instead of a recursive one, and use a queue to hold the next nodes to visit.

Comment: @amit as an exercise for myself, is the implementation of a DFS in your answer possible to transcribe to a BFS algorithm?

Comment: @riista Not directly. BFS use a loop, not a recursive call, and the remembered path is stored in a map, not on the call stack

Comment: I see. Sorry to pester, but does your method allow retrieving the *length* of the shortest path, not necessarily the shortest path itself? Since it's a DFS, it goes through every possible path. If I wanted to know the length of the shortest path, what would I do?

Comment: @riista DFS is the wrong tool to find shortest paths. That being said, iteratively-deepening BFS is not much worse than DFS: add a "maxDepth" parameter, initially set to 0, and terminate BFS if your depth reaches 0 before finding the goal. If goal not found, increment maxDepth and try again. The first time you find the goal, maxDepth will be the smallest depth at which it *can* be found, and therefore the path will be optimal.

Comment: @tucuxi, yes, I'm just struggling a touch to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code:

```
public static boolean DFS(int[][] adj, boolean[] visited, int n, int i, int o){        
    visited[i]= true;
    boolean good = false;
    if (i+1 != o) {
        for (int j = 0; j<n;j++){
            if(!(visited[j]) && adj[i][j]==1){
               good |= DFS(adj, visited, n, j, o);
            }
        }
    } else {
        good = true;
    }
    if (good) System.out.print(" " + (i+1));
    return good;
}
```

This will print paths in reverse (from end to start) - but it will only print nodes that are part of a good path. If you need to print the path in start-to-end order, you can store it in an array and then print it in reverse:

```
public static void DFS(int[][] adj, boolean[] visited, 
       ArrayList<int> path, int n, int i, int o){        
    visited[i]= true;
    if (i+1 != o) {
        for (int j = 0; j<n;j++){
            if(!(visited[j]) && adj[i][j]==1){
               path.add(j);
               DFS(adj, visited, n, j, o);
               path.remove(path.size()-1);
            }
        }
    } else {
        // show path
        for (int i : path) {
            System.out.print(" " + i);
        }
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you finally reach your destination, the method stack will have the path.

```
  ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(); // this will have your path.
  public static boolean DFS(int[][] adj, boolean[] visited, int n, int i, int o){
    if(i==o){
       list.add(o);
      //System.out.println(i);
      return true;
    }
    visited[i]= true;
    for (int j = 0; j<n;j++){
       if(!(visited[j]) && adj[i][j]==1){
          if(DFS(adj, visited, n, j, o)){
              list.add(0,j);
              //System.out.println(j);
              return true;
           }
         }
     }
   return false;
  }
```

Comment: Also note that this returns paths in reverse order

Comment: @tucuxi I copy pasted his code and started editing it and forgot to change it. Thank you :)

About reverse path, yes it is but I don't think it's really hard for OP to change it.

Comment: You are still missing `return false;` at the end, or it won't compile.